# For a normal operator is it true that $\|T^*T^2\| = \|T^3\|$?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces

For a normal operator is it always true that $\|T^*T^2\| = \|T^3\|$?

See the accepted answer for the case in a Hilbert space

Update: how about $\|T^*T^2\| = \|T\|^3$ in a Hilbert space

Comment: are we in a Hilbert/inner-product space or in a arbitrary Banach/normed space ?

Comment: Let's say in a Hilbert Space

Comment: anyway you understood that with (a weak version of) the spectral theorem the answer is obvious ? the maximiser of $\max_{\|x\|=1} \|T x\|$ is an eigenvector of $T$ whenever it is self-adjoint or normal

Comment: I have to say I am not familiar with that consequence of the spectral theorem.

Comment: maybe you should look [at the SVD of matrices first](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition), then to the spectral theorem for matrices : if $M$ is a normal matrix then $M = U DU^*$ with $U$ unitary, $D$ diagonal (and real if $M$ is self-adjoint)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that for each vector $x$, one has $$\|T^* T^2(x)\|^2 = \langle T^* T^2(x),T^* T^2(x) \rangle = \langle TT^*T^2(x), T^2(x)\rangle = \langle T^*T^3(x),T^2(x) \rangle = \langle T^3(x),T^3(x) \rangle = \|T^3(x)\|^2.$$ Thus $$\|T^3\| = \sup_{\|x\|=1} \|T^3(x)\| = \sup_{\|x\|=1}\|T^*T^2(x)\| = \|T^*T^2\|.$$

Comment: One thing I didn't quite get is why people always use sup_|x| = 1 instead of sup_|x| $\leq$ 1

Comment: It yields the same result if you take the $\sup$ over the unit sphere, the closed unit ball or even over the open unit ball. My choice was completely arbitrary.

Comment: Oh I thought the operator norm is defined to be $sup||Ax||$ on$||x|| \leq 1$

Comment: I guess it usually is. But it is not hard to show that $ \sup_{\|x\|=1}\|T(x)\| = \sup_{\|x\|\leqq 1}\|T(x)\| = \sup_{\|x\|<1}\|T(x)\|=\sup_{x\neq 0} \|T(\|x\|^{-1}x)\|,$ for a bounded linear operator $T$. If it bothers you, feel free to edit the post.

Comment: I just realized I actually asked the wrong question. Is it also true that |T*T^2| = |T|^3?

Comment: I spent the last half hour or so playing around with norm inequalities and somehow it didn't occur to me to simply use the definition of operator norm! Nice answer.

Comment: @W.W Yes, for in this case $\|T^3\|=\|T\|^3$ holds.

Answer (score 1):

Diagonalization will help here. (When in doubt and working with normal matrices, try utilizing diagonalization!)

Write $T = UDU^*$, then $T^* = UD^* U^*$, giving that $T^*T^2 = UD^*D^2U^*$. However $T^3 = UD^3 U^*$. Since unitary conjugation does not change the operator norm, this boils down to considering $D^*D^2$ and $D^3$. Here $Dg(x) = f(x)g(x)$ for some (essentially) bounded function $f$. Then $\|D^*D^2\| = \|\overline{f}f^2\|_{\infty}$ and $\|D^3\| = \|f^3\|_{\infty}$. I'll let you take it from here.

Comment: The question originally had the tag [tag:functional-analysis], which I've just re-added. So likely, the OP considers infinite-dimensional spaces.

Comment: I tried to keep it as general as possible for that reason, particularly because of the use of the word "operator." That's almost never used in regular linear algebra parlance.